# Unable to read image using readJPEG in R

Tags: r

I have a column in my R dataframe that contains link to images.
eg. https://storage.googleapis.com/du-prd/books/images/9781668001226.jpg

When I try to read it using readJPEG it's giving below error-

"unable to open [https://storage.googleapis.com/du-prd/books/images/9781668001226.jpg"](https://storage.googleapis.com/du-prd/books/images/9781668001226.jpg%22)

So I tried running it separately to check what's happening and it gives the same error.

```
readJPEG("https://storage.googleapis.com/du-prd/books/images/9781668001226.jpg")
```

I'm not sure how to debug this as there's not much detail provided in the error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the function takes a raw vector, we can avoid having to write to disk by using `readBin` to read the jpeg as a raw vector directly from the url, and passing this to `readJPEG`:

```r
img <- "https://storage.googleapis.com/du-prd/books/images/9781668001226.jpg" |>
  readBin("raw", 1e6) |>
  jpeg::readJPEG()
```

Now `img` is an rgb array, so we can do, for example:

```r
plot(as.raster(img))
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

That function does not take URLs.

From `?jpeg::readJPEG`:

```
Usage:

     readJPEG(source, native = FALSE)
     
Arguments:

  source: Either name of the file to read from or a raw vector
          representing the JPEG file content.

  native: determines the image representation - if ‘FALSE’ (the
          default) then the result is an array, if ‘TRUE’ then the
          result is a native raster representation.
```

Fixed code:

```r
tf <- tempfile(fileext = ".jpeg")
download.file("https://storage.googleapis.com/du-prd/books/images/9781668001226.jpg", tf)
# trying URL 'https://storage.googleapis.com/du-prd/books/images/9781668001226.jpg'
# Content type 'image/jpeg' length 40093 bytes (39 KB)
# ==================================================
# downloaded 39 KB
stuff <- jpeg::readJPEG(tf)
class(stuff)
# [1] "array"
unlink(tf) # if you want/need to clean up the temp file
```

Comment: Shame that even `url(url_address)` doesn't work :/

Comment: @Colombo no, but `readJPEG(readBin(url_address, "raw", 1e6)))` does.

Comment: @AllanCameron Nice one!