# Extract dominant colors from image in R

Tags: r

I want to extract the 3 major/dominant colors from images.

'https://storage.googleapis.com/du-prd/books/images/9780385547345.jpg'

So, for this image the result will be value for Orange, Black and Blue.
Then I want to visualize this in a pie/bar chart.

I tried using various approaches like kmeans clustering, however I'm not getting the desired result.

Please note, I can't use the 'Imager' package in R.

EDITED:

The code I've written-

```
image <- 'https://storage.googleapis.com/du-prd/books/images/9780385547345.jpg' |>
  readBin("raw", 1e6) |>
  jpeg::readJPEG() 

# Extract colors without checking dimensions
pixels <- as.matrix(image)
kmeans_result <- kmeans(apply(pixels, c(1, 2), mean), centers = 3)
colors <- kmeans_result$centers
```

Output:

```
        [,1]
1 0.07815438
2 0.96756534
3 0.45184408
```

Comment: What code are you using to download and import the raster into R? What have you tried to take inventory of the colors? What does *"not getting the desired result"* mean, wrong structure, wrong values, errors/warnings, or something else? Why can you not use the `imager` package?

Comment: Are you still using the read/import code from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77842632/unable-to-read-image-using-readjpeg-in-r?

Comment: If you *colour-bin*/visualise `library(colorfindr); get_colors(img = "https://storage.googleapis.com/du-prd/books/images/9780385547345.jpg", top_n = 250)`, you will be suprised by the dominance of orange-like colours.

Comment: @r2evans
I'm new to R, so I was pretty sure my code has many mistakes. Hence, didn't add it here to ensure my original question is resolved. I've edited my question to reflect the code and output now, if at all it helps. 
I'm facing some issues while installling 'Imager' package, probably related to memory. I'm working on Rstudio browser free license.

Comment: "Installing" a package will never (?) produce problems with memory, that step is at its worst about compiling shared libraries and such. Problems with installation of R packages are almost always `'make' not found` because the tools for compiling are not found, or problems relating to dependencies (OS packages) not found. I'm not saying that `imager` is or is not going to be part of any solution, but since it need compilation and requires `fftw3,libtiff,X11` (OS) libraries, it seems more likely to me that the requirements are not met.

Comment: How are you planning to convert `kmeans_result$centers` to colours?

Comment: @Friede the image needs to be split into red, green, blue columns in a data frame, then the centers of the resulting k means can be fed via `do.call` to `rgb`, which will convert into hexadecimal color strings (see below)

Comment: @AllanCameron Yes, that sounds like an approach (+1) while `kmeans(apply(pixels, c(1, 2), mean), centers = 3)` does not.

Answer (score 1):

I think your kmeans clustering approach will work quite well with a couple of tweaks.

First, let's read the image and look at it:

```r
img <- "https://storage.googleapis.com/du-prd/books/images/9780385547345.jpg" |>
  readBin("raw", 1e6) |>
  jpeg::readJPEG() 

plot(as.raster(img))
```

[image]

We can turn the image into a red, green, blue data frame as follows:

```
img_df <- data.frame(red = c(img[,,1]), green = c(img[,,2]), blue = c(img[,,3]))
```

Now let's do a kmeans clustering on the result. There's no need to scale the data in this case. Since we don't want the three main colors to be "contaminated" by the less frequent colors, we can take 10 centers and select just the three most frequent.

```
km     <- kmeans(img_df, 10)
pal    <- do.call("rgb", as.data.frame(km$centers[order(-km$size),][1:3,]))
pal
#> [1] "#FE845B" "#210D07" "#068AC8"
```

Now let's make a pie chart using these colors. We will use the cluster sizes as proportional weights for our pie chart so it has approximately the same color mix as the original image:

```
library(ggplot2)

data.frame(x = 1, y = rev(tail(sort(km$size), 3)), fill = pal) |>
  ggplot(aes(x, y, fill = fill)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_fill_identity() +
  coord_polar(theta = "y") +
  theme_void()
```

[image]